# Why onError in <Image> calls every time even if Image uri is true in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i want to load static Image if URL based Image is failed on load. i've used onError method to achieve this. but onError method calls every time even if URL is correct please any solutions, here is my code.......

```
<Image onError={(e)=>{
                console.log('-=-=-=-=-=',e)
                this.setState({profileimage:`${Config.SOURCE_URL}resize/45x45/not_found_images/NoImage-user.png`})
              }}
                source={{ uri: `${this.state.profileimage}` }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need some more information:

- Why is the tag of the emlement `Image`? The html tag for an image is `img`
- What is the inital state of `profileimage` ?

Try to change your example to following code:

```
<img onError={e => {/*set fallback image*/}} source={this.state.profileimage} />
```

Comment: well this code is not for HTML tag and it is for react-native. initial state of app is null.

Comment: Try to set the inital state to the URL before rendering the image. The tag is trying to load the URL `null` and as result calling `onError`.